# JSON format to excel

Tags: java, json, excel

I have a response in JSOn format, is there any way that I can convert it into excel sheet with a click of button in my page?

["abcd","business desc ","John","Analyst","abc@yahoo.com","(xxx)xxx-xxxx","2","167600"]

Thanks!

Comment: "with a click of a button" is rather broad.  I can make nearly anything appear to happen with the click of a button if there are not other constrains.  I assume you have other constraints, what are they?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a difficult task at all. The development section of excel provides you with a pretty basic IDE to use with Visual Basic for Application (VBA). Here is a link to a simple class library that I have used once:

http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html

Its simple as it uses the native objects to VBA to deal with JSON format.